# Align center of the view to edge of other view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 views, for example it's 2 ImageView. And I want them to look like this
[image]

So Center of the View2 is alignedTop of the View1, and Horizontal center of View1 is same as View2.

Current code is

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/colorLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/colorList"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/brightBarLayout"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/brightBarLayout"
    android:layout_below="@+id/brightBarLayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"        
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/colorPicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtnFaveColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_color_fave" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I'm dynamically setting marginTop for the View1 based on View2.heigh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but with such margin it will be not center on some devices as i know

Comment: No, you are not exactly right. If you use **dp**, everything will be ok. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) about difference beetween different metrics. With best regards.